# Android Studio "class" or "interface" expected

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am following instruction provide in http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html to display user location. But leading to above stated compilation error.

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //ERROR '}' expected

        protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    } // ERROR 'class' or 'interface' expected


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            tv1.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            tv1.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

I go through the error and found its a syntax error. Can anyone tell me why it is failing in compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `buildGoogleApiClient` method can't be inside your `onCreate` method.

Change it to :

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buildGoogleApiClient ();
}
```

Or :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer @Eran. But did you went through the link which i provided in the beginning.?

There they have clearly mentioned **"In your activity's onCreate() method, create an instance of Google API Client using GoogleApiClient.Builder. Use the builder to add the LocationServices API."**

Comment: @h.APP.y I didn't go through the link. If you need to create the instance of Google API Client in your onCreate, just put that statement directly in onCreate. Don't put it inside another method.

Comment: For your first example, don't you need to call the actual buildGoogleApiClient() method inside of onCreate() to create the instance of Google API client?

Comment: @committedandroider That's another option. My first example only suggested how to fix the compilation error. I wasn't originally aware that method had to be called by onCreate. It's a good idea though!

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //ERROR '}' expected

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
} // ERROR 'class' or 'interface' expected
```

Should be:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); } // curly brace to close method and clean up error

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
// removing this curly brace should clear up the error here
```

Your syntax was off because of misplaced curly braces. Watch out for the little things.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to define a function ( buildGoogleApiClient ) inside another function ( onCreate ) which is not possible with Java.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    //
    // Body of this function
    //
}
```

So basically in Java curly braces mark the boundaries of a code block. A code block can be a if-block, while-block or function-block etc. Java does not allow a function-block inside a function-block. Only class-block can contain a function-block.

So, you need to define your functions directly under the class-block.

```
public class Blah extends Activity implements BlahInterface {

    private BlahApiClient mBlahApiClient;

    protected synchronized void buildBlahApiClient() {
        mBlahApiClient = new BlahApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    }

    protected void onCreate( Bundel savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // You can call (execute) any defined function inside this function
        buildBlahApiClient();

   }

}
```